# I'm trying to validate the domains from a .csv file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Here is what I have and not working:

```
for i in `cat cnames.csv`

    do nslookup $i | grep -v "8.8.8.8\|=\|Non-authoritative" >> output.txt
done
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: You are missing a `; do` after the `for i in ...`. Also please explain the content of `cnames.csv`. A short extract would be helpful.

Comment: No semicolon is needed if `do` appears on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); you don't iterate over a file using a `for` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
     nslookup "$i"
done < cnames.csv  | grep -v "8.8.8.8\|=\|Non-authoritative" > output.txt
```

Note that you don't need to run `grep` separate for each call to `nslookup`; you can pipe the aggregate output to a single call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exit status of `nslookup`.

```
for i in $(cat cnames.csv); do
    if nslookup "$i"; then
        echo "$i is valid"
    else
        echo "$i not found"
    fi
done
```

Is `cnames.csv` a *real* .csv file? Wouldn't that require to extract only the column with addresses in them? Right now the commas and other fields (if existing) are read too.

Comment: Yes it is a real .csv file. Here is my code so far. I remove all duplicates and empty strings:

Comment: #Running command
if [ -z $"cname" ]
 then
  `mssql -f csv -c /path/to/mssql.json -q SELECT * from cname WHERE cname IS NULL OR cname = ""` > /tmp/cnames.csv
fi

#Validate cnames
for i in `cat /tmp/cnames.csv`
 do nslookup $i | grep -v "8.8.8.8\|=\|Non-authoritative" >> /tmp/output.txt
 done

Comment: @jphil1971 We cannot help you if you don't show the contents of cnames.csv. Please include a *small* example into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get them all looked up faster in parallel and more succinctly with **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel -a cnames.csv nslookup {} | grep ...
```